# Thermal expansion of the oceans versus thermal expansion of land masses

Tags: temperature, geophysics, climate-science

I am told that some, (about half of the 3 mm per year), rise in the sea level, is due to the thermal expansion of the oceans. But thermal expansion should affect the land masses also, so shouldn't the thermal expansion of the land masses offset that of the Ocean, at least to some extent? Why is this never mentioned?

Comment: because the oceans are water that are conductive to heat to their whole volume, but landmasses only heat at the top , the temperature  after a few meters down is unaffected by the temperature of the air.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient " The effects of weather, sun, and season only reach a depth of approximately 10-20 metres. "

Comment: Thanks for that answer. But not entirely true I think. Oceans also have a temperature gradient to their depths, maybe not as steep.

Comment: They do , but because they are following fluid dynamics, they can expand.